# How to properly set property(if user is logged) from cookie after page opens or F5 in React with router and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, router

I would like to know what is the **best practise** in my case.

I am checking cookies in App constructor if there is stored a token. If it is there I am dispatching action which will set property `isAuth` to true.

My problem is that I will get redirected to login because isAuth is false from the beginning.

I came up with solution that I will set `isAuth` after checking session and I will not redner anything until then. **Is it OK?** And even if is, isn't there a better solution for handling this?

```
return (
    <div>
         <Router>
              {isAuth ? (
                   <Switch>
                        auth routes...    
                   </Switch>
                   ) 
                   : (
                   <Switch>
                        login and redirect to login
                   </Switch>
                   )}
         </Router>
     </div>
);
```

Comment: Yiu can initialize isAuth to null and if it is still null, you will display an 'is loading' message or a spinner.

Comment: Btw, what did you mean in F5?

Comment: I did it like that. Spinner is not very good solution, because it is delayed just because of Redux, so it would just blink. On the other hand, setTimeoutfor some random time in range 0.3-1s would solve that. F5 means refreshing page.

Comment: What about loading it directly in reducer?

Comment: You are not supposed to do such things in the reducer... Just to update the state from values.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a `PrivateRoute` component that renders the `Route` or `Redirect` components after checking the login status, something like:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...otherProps }) => (
    <Route
        { ...otherProps }
        render={ props => (
            isLoggedIn()
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={ Paths.LOGIN } />
        )}
    />
)
```

You should replace my `isLoggedIn` method and my `Paths.LOGIN` constants with your case.

Then you just use them as:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/admin/something" component={ MyAdminPage } />
<Route path="/non/logged/in/route" component={ MyNonLoggedInPage } />
<Route path="/login" component={ LogInPage } />
```